# ASP.NET in Visual Studio 2013 with Simple Membership: How to View ALL USERS

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, simplemembership

I created a website in ASP.NET MVC 4 and used the built in simple membership. I registered as a test user and logged in. I just want to be able to have a database view of these users that register somewhere... I can't find anything.

I thought the web admin tool was the answer, and I found a way to get to it through command prompt, but the "security" tab displays an error and upon further research I found that it doesn't even work with simple membership.

Ideally I need to use simple membership to set up roles (I want admin and non admin). I feel like this should be very easy, but any documentation I find is incomplete, uses old classes that are no longer a part of the template, or just don't work...

Thanks.

Comment: You really can't find anything?

Comment: I've found a lot of blogs, but all of them just regard the old way of ASP membership, not simplemembership. The ones that use simplemembership never seem to discuss WHERE to view/access those users and how to set roles for them.